# change xef/xbc/x9e and other to normal character html

Tags: javascript, html

i get the data from a server and that is transferred to the main page with this command

```
document.getElementById("ft").innerHTML +=(endata);
```

the problem is that the server send data with those character and many more
`\xe2\x80\xa6`

`\xef\xbd\x9e`

or some Chinese, Korean, and Japanese characters also.

put having this `\xef\xbd\x9e` character instead of > is not beautiful
so how could I do to make the insert code send by the server not have this code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that they send uri encoded character.

Try this:

```js
const encoded = '\xe2\x80\xa6';
console.log(decodeURI(encoded));
```

Comment: thanks but when i alwready give what the serveur will send it works but when the texts comes from a variable that what he receive in websocket it doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: no idea but I'm not sure to understand your problem. If you want to change server code, please provide the server code that send the datas